# Azure portal sign in error - sign in a new device

Tags: azure, azureportal

I have 2 azure ad accounts in the same tenant, and I always use office computer to sign in azure portal. But recently I met a problem. When I use one of the account login in azure portal by my phone or use my personal computer, it redirects to an error page and showed I was trying to login in **a new device** and asked me to contact admin. But actually my account has global admin role. The strangest point is, when I used another account I can sign in successfully and this account even don't have admin role.

**What I have tried**: I tried to remove my admin role but it makes no effect. When I reassigned admin role to my account, it still showed the same error. I also compared with other properties but there are no differences.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered a similar problem before. I think it has nothing to do with your account role. It only shows this prompt for a certain account. As you said in the question, the account has the same attributes as other accounts.

My suggestion is: try to log in again after a while, or change to another phone to log in.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I met this problem several days before, but it still the same now. By the way, I have no other devices. So, any other idea ? QAQ

Comment: I found it very...amazing? I did nothing on it but actually it has been ok now. I can login successfully.